# I have a small problem with the (if) command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

First, I will show my project

```
$url = Read-Host 'URL'
if ( $url -notmatch '\.'){
    msg * "The title does not contain(.)"
}
```

Explanation of the code

The code should alert you that the site does not have a `.`

The problem is that the code alerts you if the link contains a `.` Once, I want him to alert me if he finds it`.` twice

**Example (pseudo code):**

```
$url = Read-Host 'URL'
if ( $url -notmatch '\.' = 2){
    msg * "The title does not contain 2 (.)"
}
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator. Are you using a code editor? You should see an error when typing an if construct incorrectly.

Comment: I know it's wrong, this is just an example of what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=` is an assignment and not an operator for equality.

If you want the given url to have at least 2 dots in it, try

```
$url = Read-Host 'URL'
if ( [regex]::matches($Url, '\.').Count -lt 2 ){
    msg * "The url does not contain at least 2 dots (.)"
}
```